# How to give the server port to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a node server with several node projects. I use nginx to get them all responding on port 80. Now, this works for the initial http request. For the websockets, I need to use the direct server port. To keep everything alive while developing I would like to try this, projects will have a dev and live version. Once de dev is stable, I will copy it to the live folder. The live folder is runned by a systemctl script where I define a difrent port to the live version so I can dev without taking the live down. The problem I encounter now is, how can I get the running server port in my client side Javascript so that the dev page connect to the dev port and visa versa?

currently I'm only using express, socket.io and mysql. I have no further npm packages installed. I searched allot but there is not to mush I can find. I found how to connect the socket to the page url but I cannot use that because that URL will always be on port 80. Further I found allot of huge packages that has no use for me since the original page is just static, the dynamics all run over websockets.

Is there any way to parse the port number in the clients .js file like I could do fairly easy in php? And if so, what would be the most efficient way. I could let javascript check if the page uses the live or dev URL but I would prefer not to hardcode my dev URL into JS where it is for everyone to see.

Answer (score 0):

1. run a third node.js socket.io server program, all your clients connect to this server first.
2. In this simple node.js program, determine the type of clients by any means.  e.g. different user id for dev/production users
3. send the server url and port to your client according to its type (dev or production)
4. you may also use this technique to separate your users to different production servers.